# Uninstall Aobo Keylogger

Tags: macos, uninstall

Really not sure how to uninstall Aobo Keylogger for Mac. It's sooo annoying in my "status bar" at the top of my MacBook Pro. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

From [ehow.com](http://www.ehow.com/how_6759031_uninstall-aobo-keylogger.html):

- Select Users in System Preferences
- Select "Login Startup" and highlight Aobo
- Press <kbd>-</kbd> button
- Click on "Library" and drag-and-drop Aobo to the trash.